# How to index two date columns for this kind of query

Tags: mysql, database-design, date, indexing

I'm having a MySQL-Table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `dates` (
`id`  int UNSIGNED NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`object_id`  int UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
`date_from`  date NOT NULL ,
`date_to`  date NULL ,
`time_from`  time NULL ,
`time_to`  time NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

which is queried mostly this way:

```
SELECT object_id FROM `dates`
WHERE NOW() BETWEEN date_from AND date_to
```

How do I index the table best? Should I create two indexes, one for `date_from` and one for `date_to` or is a combined index on both columns better?

Comment: I feel date_from is better to create index instead of combined

Comment: You [probably] feel wrong.  Say there are 10 rows for some object.  8 have an end date in the past, 1 is "current", and 1 is "future".  How many of those get filtered out by "NOW()>date_from" (answer : only one) and how many get filtered out by "NOW()<date_to" (answer : 8).  What do you use indexes for ?  To retain as much rows as possible as long as possible ?  Or to filter out as many as possible as soon as possible ?  Your "feel" is only correct if the number of "rows in the future" are likely to be higher than the number of "rows in the past".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the query:

```
WHERE NOW() >= date_from 
  AND NOW() <= date_to
```

A compound index `(date_from, date_to)` is useless.

Create both indices: `(date_from)` and `(date_to)` and let the SQL optimizer decide each time which one to use. Depending on the values and the selectivity, the optimizer may choose one or the other index. Or none of them. There is no easy way to create an index that will take both conditions into consideration.

---

(A spatial index could be used to optimize such a condition, if you could translate the dates to latitude and longitude).

**Update**

My mistake. An index on `(date_from, date_to, object_id)` can and is indeed used in some situations for this query. If the selectivity of the `NOW() <= date_from` is high enough, the optimizer chooses to use this index, than doing a full scan on the table or using another index. This is because it's a covering index, meaning no data is needed to be fetched from the table, only reading from the index data is required.

Minor note (not related to performance, only correctness of the query). Your condition is equivalent to:

```
WHERE CURRENT_DATE() >= date_from 
  AND ( CURRENT_DATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY <= date_to
       OR  ( CURRENT_DATE() = NOW() 
         AND CURRENT_DATE() = date_to
           )
      )
```

Are you sure you want that or do you want this:

```
WHERE CURRENT_DATE() >= date_from 
  AND CURRENT_DATE() <= date_to
```

The `NOW()` function returns a `DATETIME`, while `CURRENT_DATE()` returns a `DATE`, without the time part.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - basically I have two kinds of a query: either I am selecting by `object_id` to get all related dates for my object or by choosing a date range where a selected day (be it `NOW()` or any other date) is between `date_from` and `date_to` so I get all rows that happen that day.

Answer (score 3):

You should create an index covering date_from, date_to and object_id as explained by ypercube.  The order of the fields in the index is dependant on whether you will have more data for the past or the future.  As pointed out by Erwin in response to Sanjay's comment, the date_to field will be more selective if you have more dates in the past and vice versa.

```
CREATE INDEX ON (date_to, date_from, object_id);
```

Answer (score 1):

How many rows in relation to your table size does your query return? If it's more than 10 percent i would not bother to create an index, in such a case your quite close to a table scan anyway. If it's well below 10 percent, then in this case, would use an index containg 
(date_from, date_to, object_id) so, that the query result can be constructed entirely from the information in the index, without the database havind to track back to the table data to get the value for object_id.

Depending on the size of your table this can use up alot of space. If you can spare that, give it a try.

Comment: I didn't know that the selected field is then taken from the index, good to know! I guess the row count is five-digit and the matches are less than 10 percent. So this seems like the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Create an index with (date_from,date_to) as that single index would be usable for the WHERE criteria

If you create separate indexes then MySQL will have to use one or the other instead of both